# I need Azure DevOps REST API to set permission for group itself as well as on repositories, pipeline and releases

Tags: api, rest, azure-devops

I have created a Azure DevOps project and a project groups "DevGroup" using AzureDevOpsDemogenerator by own template "https://azuredevopsdemogenerator-core.azurewebsites.net/extractor/index" but looks like using template of azuredevopsdemogenerator we cant export custom groups permission. Now I want to set permission for "DevGroup" group and allow everything at project level as well as object level like Repository, pipeline and release using preferably REST API.

Can you suggest any of the option:

1. Is there a way to export permission as well along with groups in azuredevopsdemogenerator own template?
   If not
2. Do we have Azure DevOps REST API where i can pass org name, project name, groups and object etc. to set the permission?

Thanks
Den

Answer (score 1):

Group permissions are not supported in the Azure DevOps Demo Generator. You will have to do this post creation of the project. You may want to see if this works for you: [Azure DevOps REST API - Request Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/request%20access/request%20access?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)